# Change color of a rectangle inside a class, like a status

Tags: java, javafx, changelistener

So far i tried so many different things to make this work. I can't seem to understand why this shouldn't work.
I have a class called `StatusRect.java`. 
This class returns a rectangle when a new object is being made with the method `makeRectangleStatus`.
The idea is to color this rectangle every time an integer becomes a certain value.
In the class `StatusRect.java` the method `changeIntFlag` is invoked from another class. Here the integer is being changed. That works.

Now I just want the color of the rectangle to change in this `StatusRect.java` class.
The main question is actually can this color be set inside this `StatusRect.java` class, or can it only be done outside this class?
The rectangle object is being made in the `Stage` of the application like below. There the color `red` is given as a parameter.
Any help here is greatly appreciated.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception { 

    Rectangle rec = new StatusRect().makeRectangleStatus(50, 700, 20, 20, "red", "black", "btnObj1", 7, 0);

}
```

*StatusRect class:*

```
    public class StatusRect {

        private String ColorStatusOn;
        private String ColorStatusOff;
        private int IntFlag;
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(); 


        public Rectangle makeRectangleStatus (double x, double y, double Witdh, double Height, String ColorStatOn, String ColorStatOff, String BtnId, int SetIntStatus, int Current){
            rec.setLayoutX(x);
            rec.setLayoutY(y);
            rec.setWidth(Witdh);
            rec.setHeight(Height);                   
            ColorStatusOn = ColorStatOn;
            return rec;
        }  

        public void changeIntFlag(int iEnabled) {
            if(IntFlag == iEnabled) return;
            IntFlag = iEnabled;
            System.out.println("VALUE CHANGED!!!: " + IntFlag);
            if (IntFlag == 7){

                //this is being triggerd every time the int Flag value becomes "7"
                System.out.println("SAME NUMBER: SET COLOR RECTANGLE TO red"); 

                //Why doesnt the color change here?? 
                rec.setStyle("-fx-fill:" + ColorStatusOn); 
            }                 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it can. Can you show the code you have tried to actually change it (i.e. where are you calling `changeIntFlag(...)`)?

Comment: @James: 
public void send(MidiMessage InputMsg, long timeStamp) {
new StatusRect().changeIntFlag(Channel); //this method is triggerd automatically when a message is received. Channel is the int value that changes with every new message.

}

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `makeRectangleStatus` method (and if it is necessary your `Rectangle` class adding some setters/getters) and set the colour of `this.rec` directly inside `makeRectangleStatus`.  For instance, if you want that your Rectangle instance goes to `ColorStatOn` string, try this:

```
public void makeRectangleStatus (double x, double y, double Witdh, double Height, String ColorStatOn, String ColorStatOff, String BtnId, int SetIntStatus, int Current){
    rec.setLayoutX(x);
    rec.setLayoutY(y);
    rec.setWidth(Witdh);
    rec.setHeight(Height); 
    rec.setColorStatOn(ColorStatOn);
}
```

Besides pay attention: you don't need to return anything in `makeRectangleStatus` since you are using `this.rec` object.

Comment: I doubt that [this is the OP's own `Rectangle` class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html)

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana: Yes, using a setter to change it directly inside makeRectangleStatus make most sense, however the object is only created once so therefore values are not being updated. The setvalue should be updated every time it changes. I have tried to solve it with changelistener but without luck.

Comment: rec.setColorStatOn is no valid rectangle property. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed is that all the changes of styles from objects, rectangles buttons,etc work with events. Like action event, move, touch etc. 
So when an action is true then something is changed. Just making a set method and setting a value doesnt do anything. You have to evaluate the value and add for example a changeproperty listener to it. Like with a slider, when the value of the property of the slider changes, and binding it. Objects are created only once.
I tried to do this like below. I understood that the method called "changed" is invoked when the value of the property changes, but sadly that doesnt work.
I think this is the way it should work, but Iam no expert.

```
IntegerProperty currentvalue = new SimpleIntegerProperty(IntFlag);
currentvalue.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue <? extends Number>
observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue){
System.out.println("CHANGED, LISTENER TRIGGERD!!!!" +newValue);
}
});
```